# How to find the index of an item in a multidimensional array swiftily?

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have this array:

```
let a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Now I want something like this:

```
public func indicesOf(x: Int, array: [[Int]]) -> (Int, Int) {
    ...
}
```

so that I can call it like this:

```
indicesOf(7, array: a) // returns (2, 0)
```

Of course, I can use:

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    for j in 0..<array[i].count {
        if array[i][j] == x {
            return (i, j)
        }
    }
}
```

But that is not even close to swifty!

I want a way to do this which is swifty. I think maybe I can use `reduce` or `map`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense using `map/filter/reduce` for this case because you don't need to transform a list of something into a list of another thing. You just gotta do some kind of equality check between values using `enumerate()` if you think subscript and `.count` looks ugly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simplify your code slightly with `enumerate()` and `indexOf()`.
Also the function should return an optional tuple because the element
might not be present in the "matrix". Finally, you can make it generic:

```
func indicesOf<T: Equatable>(x: T, array: [[T]]) -> (Int, Int)? {
    for (i, row) in array.enumerate() {
        if let j = row.indexOf(x) {
            return (i, j)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

You can also make it an extension for a nested `Array` of `Equatable`
elements:

```
extension Array where Element : CollectionType,
    Element.Generator.Element : Equatable, Element.Index == Int {
    func indicesOf(x: Element.Generator.Element) -> (Int, Int)? {
        for (i, row) in self.enumerate() {
            if let j = row.indexOf(x) {
                return (i, j)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

if let (i, j) = a.indicesOf(7) {
    print(i, j)
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
extension Array where Element : Collection,
    Element.Iterator.Element : Equatable, Element.Index == Int {
    
    func indices(of x: Element.Iterator.Element) -> (Int, Int)? {
        for (i, row) in self.enumerated() {
            if let j = row.index(of: x) {
                return (i, j)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Swift 5+**

```
extension Array where Element : Collection,
    Element.Iterator.Element : Equatable, Element.Index == Int {
    func indicesOf(x: Element.Iterator.Element) -> (Int, Int)? {
        for (i, row) in self.enumerated() {
            if let j = row.firstIndex(of: x) {
                return (i, j)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't know that `enumerate` is _this_ useful until now!

Answer (score 8):

Version accepting a closure, similar to [index(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index), so there it is usable on the array of any elements, not only `Equatable`

```
extension Array where Element : Collection, Element.Index == Int {
  func indices(where predicate: (Element.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> (Int, Int)? {
    for (i, row) in self.enumerated() {
      if let j = row.index(where: predicate) {
        return (i, j)
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```
let testArray = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8]]

let testNumber = 6

print(testArray.indices(of: testNumber))
print(testArray.indices{$0 == testNumber})

Optional((1, 2))
Optional((1, 2))
```

Also, it can be used with `IndexPath`:

```
extension Array where Element : Collection, Element.Index == Int {
  func indexPath(where predicate: (Element.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> IndexPath? {
    for (i, row) in self.enumerated() {
      if let j = row.index(where: predicate) {
        return IndexPath(indexes: [i, j])
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```