# What is the most efficient way of editing this element in a multidimensional array?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to change the string of an element in an array that is within another array. See below:

```
let arr: [[String]] = [["Florida", "US"], ["New York", "US"], ["Georgia", "US"]]
```

Assuming we do not know the position of the array:

```
["Florida", "US"]
```

What is the most efficient method of replacing "Florida" for example with "Maine" without using a loop so that the end result is:

```
[["Maine", "US"], ["New York", "US"], ["Georgia", "US"]]
```

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary<String,String>` (if your use case is the one described above, you can easily transform it into a Dictionary by using `init(grouping:by:)`) ? Worst case, using that array will always be O(n) since you have to iterate all of it.

Comment: This may be a viable option. I'll try it out.

Comment: Didn't see your swift3 tag: [init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init) is part of Swift 4

Comment: Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/37315028/1187415 you could write `if let idx = arr.indices(of: "Florida") { arr[idx.0][idx.1] = "Maine" }`

Comment: @MartinR This would also work. I'll give this option a try as well

Answer (score 0):

Without some form of indexing in your native structure (e.g. a Dictionary instead of an array) or maintaining sorted values in the array, the best you can achieve is O(n/2).

```
var arr: [[String]] = [["Florida", "US"], ["New York", "US"], ["Georgia", "US"]]

// A simple map() would always be O(n)
arr = arr.map{$0 == ["Florida", "US"] ? ["Maine", "US"] : $0 }

// Finding the element's index would be O(n/2) on average
if let index = arr.index(where: {$0 == ["Florida", "US"]}) 
{ arr[index] = ["Maine", "US"] }
```