# Search for a value in two dimensional array

Tags: swift, xcode

How do I search for the value "Mexico" in a two dimensional array below?

```
// this is our array of arrays
var groups = [[String]]()

// we create three simple string arrays for testing
var groupA = ["England", "Ireland", "Scotland", "Wales"]
var groupB = ["Canada", "Mexico", "United States"]
var groupC = ["China", "Japan", "South Korea"]

// then add them all to the "groups" array
groups.append(groupA)
groups.append(groupB)
groups.append(groupC)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: I would like to return the array index number which would be 1 for Mexico as Canada is 0 and United States is 2

Comment: And index is 1 for Ireland and Japan as well.... Add a proper explanation of the expected result to your question.

Comment: If you want it by Index, Here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314322/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-multidimensional-array-swiftily

Comment: Correct and that is fine. The position of where one country is in any of the array is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function which i implemented which checks if an element is listed within the multi-dimension array and returns the total elements found:

- using .flatMap(_:) to flattened the multi-dimension arrays into one level.
- using .filter(_:) to return the elements that are allowed based on the predicate.

  ```
  import UIKit

  var groups = [[String]]()

  // we create three simple string arrays for testing
  var groupA = ["England", "Ireland", "Scotland", "Wales"]
  var groupB = ["Canada", "Mexico", "United States"]
  var groupC = ["China", "Japan", "South Korea"]

  // then add them all to the "groups" array
  groups.append(groupA)
  groups.append(groupB)
  groups.append(groupC)

  func findElementInMultiDimension(element: String) -> Int {
      var count = 0
      let _ = groups.flatMap{$0.filter { (item) -> Bool in
          if item.contains(element) {
              count = count + 1
              return true
          } else {
              return false
          }
          }}
      return count
  }

  findElementInMultiDimension(element: "Mexico")
  print(findElementInMultiDimension(element: "Mexico")) //prints 1
  ```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **`filter(_:)`** and **`contains(_:)`** to get the particular `group` in `groups` `array` that contains `Mexico` or any other value, i.e.

```
let searchText = "Mexico"
let group = groups.filter({ $0.contains(searchText) })
```

And in case you simply want true/false to whether "Mexico" exist in groups or not, you can use **`flatMap(_:)`** along with **`contains(_:)`**, i.e.

```
let contains = groups.flatMap({ $0 }).contains(searchText)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you want to return an array or just a bool if the string is present. As people have already answered how to get the result array, here is a solution if you want to search if the word is present in the 2D array or not and return a Bool.

```
 let searchText = "Mexico"
 let result = groups.reduce(false) { (_, group) -> Bool in
      group.contains(searchText)
 }
 print(result) // true
```

Comment: I would like to return the array index number which would be 1 for Mexico

Comment: If you want the index, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314322/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-multidimensional-array-swiftily